# String manipulation extracting exact patterns from a string python

Tags: python

I have a text file which contains data, as appeared below, the data file contain huge amount of entries

```
{latlng: [77.7355421, 12.985924] , name: 'International Tech Park Bangalore 2.5 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.7515038, 12.9829723] , name: 'H M Tech Park 2.3 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.721544,12.981423], name: 'Prestige Featherlite Techapark 4.7km', type: 'work', icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.7434198, 12.9852629] , name: 'GR Tech Park 1.6 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.7402427, 12.9860243] , name: 'Brigade Tech Park 1.8 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.7257197, 12.9761888] , name: 'Concentrix Embassy TI  3.7 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.72577199999999, 12.9821986] , name: 'Gopalan Global Axis 3.4 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.7445732, 12.9581743] , name: 'Sigma Soft Tech Park Gamma Block 4.0 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.6911745, 12.9425392] , name: 'Prestige Tech Park II 10.4 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.710490,12.973138], name: 'Prestige Technostar 6.7 Km', type: 'work', icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.7180171, 12.9709603] , name: 'Kalyani Tech Park Private Limited 4.7 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.7053282, 12.9935253] , name: 'Bhoruka Technology Park 7.9 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.71993979999999, 12.9821174] , name: 'Mind Comp Tech Park 4.0 km' , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},
{latlng: [77.7419192, 12.9759885] , name: 'The Deens Academy 75 m' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},
{latlng: [77.7434897, 12.9758206] , name: 'Deens academy parking 0.1 km' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},
{latlng: [77.7424005, 12.976853] , name: 'Zeena English School 0.1 km' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},
{latlng: [77.7451549, 12.9747377] , name: 'Indus Early Learning Centre Whitefield 0.6 km' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},
{latlng: [77.739758, 12.976582] , name: 'Mont Ivy Preschools 0.3 km' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},
{latlng: [77.7458612, 12.9743853] , name: 'Miracle kids Pre School 0.5 km' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},
{latlng: [77.7482531, 12.9741599] , name: 'Little Millennium 0.9 km' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},
{latlng: [77.7481791, 12.9797439] , name: 'Holy Cross School and PU College 2.2 km' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},
{latlng: [77.74956259999999, 12.9770804] , name: 'St. Joseph's Convent School 1.3 km' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},
{latlng: [77.74558390000001, 12.9691268] , name: 'The Foundation School 1.7 km' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},
```

I want to extract the distance from each line in the *name* field, and separate it to a new field *distance*. For example, the last line from above:

> {latlng: [77.74558390000001, 12.9691268] , name: 'The Foundation
>   School 1.7 km' , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'}

Should transform to:

> {latlng: [77.74558390000001, 12.9691268] , name: 'The Foundation
>   School' , distance:1.7,  type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'}

I have tried to convert this int `json` but it is not the correct format of `json`, as seen below. Another thing I tried is to convert this string into list and then extract but I'm not sure that this is the right way to do it ?

```
import json
import ast
import re


with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        f = line.split()

        for i in f:
            print(type(i))
```

Would appreciate some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Rmano** said, the data need to be reformatted and unified, otherwise there is plenty of test cases that need to be checked.

Improving **Rmano** answer to get the desired output we get the following, where *t.txt* is the input you provided in the question:

```
def extract_name_substring(line):
    pre_define_pattern = r" name: '(.*) ([0-9.]+ *[kK ]m)'"
    name_dist_str = re.findall(pre_define_pattern, line)
    return "name: '" + name_dist_str[0][0] + "' , distance: " + name_dist_str[0][1]

lines = open('t.txt').read().splitlines()
new_strings = []
for line in lines:
    name_dist_str = extract_name_substring(line)
    tmp = line.split(' , ')
    new_str = tmp[0] + " , " + name_dist_str + " , " +" , ".join(tmp[2:])
    new_strings.append(new_str)

print(new_strings)
```

The resulted output is:

```
["{latlng: [77.7355421, 12.985924] , name: 'International Tech Park Bangalore' , distance: 2.5 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.7515038, 12.9829723] , name: 'H M Tech Park' , distance: 2.3 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.721544,12.981423], name: 'Prestige Featherlite Techapark 4.7km', type: 'work', icon: 'suitcase'}, , name: 'Prestige Featherlite Techapark' , distance: 4.7km , ", "{latlng: [77.7434198, 12.9852629] , name: 'GR Tech Park' , distance: 1.6 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.7402427, 12.9860243] , name: 'Brigade Tech Park' , distance: 1.8 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.7257197, 12.9761888] , name: 'Concentrix Embassy TI ' , distance: 3.7 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.72577199999999, 12.9821986] , name: 'Gopalan Global Axis' , distance: 3.4 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.7445732, 12.9581743] , name: 'Sigma Soft Tech Park Gamma Block' , distance: 4.0 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.6911745, 12.9425392] , name: 'Prestige Tech Park II' , distance: 10.4 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.710490,12.973138], name: 'Prestige Technostar 6.7 Km', type: 'work', icon: 'suitcase'}, , name: 'Prestige Technostar' , distance: 6.7 Km , ", "{latlng: [77.7180171, 12.9709603] , name: 'Kalyani Tech Park Private Limited' , distance: 4.7 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.7053282, 12.9935253] , name: 'Bhoruka Technology Park' , distance: 7.9 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.71993979999999, 12.9821174] , name: 'Mind Comp Tech Park' , distance: 4.0 km , type: 'work' , icon: 'suitcase'},", "{latlng: [77.7419192, 12.9759885] , name: 'The Deens Academy' , distance: 75 m , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},", "{latlng: [77.7434897, 12.9758206] , name: 'Deens academy parking' , distance: 0.1 km , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},", "{latlng: [77.7424005, 12.976853] , name: 'Zeena English School' , distance: 0.1 km , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},", "{latlng: [77.7451549, 12.9747377] , name: 'Indus Early Learning Centre Whitefield' , distance: 0.6 km , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},", "{latlng: [77.739758, 12.976582] , name: 'Mont Ivy Preschools' , distance: 0.3 km , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},", "{latlng: [77.7458612, 12.9743853] , name: 'Miracle kids Pre School' , distance: 0.5 km , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},", "{latlng: [77.7482531, 12.9741599] , name: 'Little Millennium' , distance: 0.9 km , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},", "{latlng: [77.7481791, 12.9797439] , name: 'Holy Cross School and PU College' , distance: 2.2 km , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},", "{latlng: [77.74956259999999, 12.9770804] , name: 'St. Joseph's Convent School' , distance: 1.3 km , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},", "{latlng: [77.74558390000001, 12.9691268] , name: 'The Foundation School' , distance: 1.7 km , type: 'learn' , icon: 'student'},"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Data is a bit strange, I think that the data should be reformat and made more uniform, for example you have *km, Km, m*, with space before and without space.

The following seems to work, for the snippet of data you gave:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import re

myre=r"name: '(.*) ([0-9.]+ *[kK ]m)'"

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        data = re.search(myre, line)
        print ("place:", data.group(1), "distance:", data.group(2))
```

Output:

```
place: International Tech Park Bangalore distance: 2.5 km
place: H M Tech Park distance: 2.3 km
place: Prestige Featherlite Techapark distance: 4.7km
place: GR Tech Park distance: 1.6 km
```

Obviously, you have to check for errors, no matches, and probably compile the regular expression.
(if there are more non uniformity, you have to adapt the regex to it)